# Client Side Validation Doesn't Work In Nested Layouts in Asp.Net Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, layout, razor-pages, client-side-validation

I have created a Students specific layout in my Razor Pages application and put it inside _Layout as a nested layout.Now the problem is when the Create page is opened within _StudentLayout,the client side validation doesn't work! However,when the Create page is opened normally,which means inside the application's _Layout,it does work well!
Here's the code at the top of Create:

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_StudentLayout.cshtml";}
```

Here's the code inside _StudentLayout:

```
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @{
                Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
            }
            <div class="mt-3">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
```

How should make client side validation work within a nested layout? What's the problem here?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting errors? Have you checked the browser's console for any hints?

Comment: @MikeBrind I mean the client side validation won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the scripts to the nested layout(_StudentLayout) and now the client site validation is working,but this solution doesn't sound right to me.The way I see it,once you have everything loaded in the _Layout,the nested layouts should ideally pick them up without needing to put them again in the nested layouts.Any opinions?
Here's what I did:

```
            ...
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @{
                Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
            }
            <div class="mt-3">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/Bootstrap4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```